# Can't see CloudRun monitoring Metrics - What IAM Policy is Missing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In CloudRun, my developer can't see the metrics on the CloudRun service dashboard, but they can see the metrics on the metrics dashboard. What policy am I missing?

**The CloudRun Dashboard Missing Metrics Charts:**

[image]

**The IAM Policy:**

[image]

**Expected Dashboard:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you have a pop-up blocker or any kind of blocker extension

Comment: Tried a few different browsers, no pop-up blockers and still no data coming on the small metrics dashboards :-(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this and get some data on the graphs by granting the user the role of **Monitoring Viewer**.
Since you already have that, @valentin22 answer might still be worth a try.

[image]